# Obtener el password desde un alertdialog

Tags: java, android-studio

Sres, 
Tengo un problemita con el alertDialog.  Hice un una ventana de alerta para ingresar el password y un botón.  Al apretar el botón, tiene almacenar en una variable String el dato ingresado.  Pero me sale error cuando hago el click en la linea de `passwordIngresado = contrasena.getText().toString();`
Si me pueden ayudar.  Gracias

```
public AlertDialog createLoginDialogo(Context context) {

    final TextView contrasena = findViewById(R.id.contrasena_input);

    Context mContext = context;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    Button ingreso = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.entrar_boton);

    ingreso.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"singin el programa.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                passwordIngresado = contrasena.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    );

    Log.d("EditarConfig", "2:" + passwordIngresado);
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: podrias agregar el mensaje de error que te aparece.

Comment: Es importante agregar el mensaje de error, de lo contrario varias podrían ser las causas, por favor revisa [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Tienes sin declarar passwordIngresado. Añádele String antes:

```
String passwordIngresado = contrasena.getText().toString();
```

Cuando tengas fallos aporta todos los mensajes de error que tengas. Así es más sencillo ayudarte. En los propios mensajes de error te dicen exactamente cual es el problema y donde está ubicado.

Comment: Si no tuviera declarada la variable passwordIngresado , no le provocaría un error en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

La linea final `TextView contrasena = findViewById(R.id.contrasena_input);` tendría que hacer referencia a la vista:

```
  TextView contrasena = v.findViewById(R.id.contrasena_input);
```